# Is $\{x : \sin{\frac{1}{x}} > 0 \}$ open/closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The set consists of elements that satisfy $0 < \frac{1}{x} < \pi$ (and $2\pi$ repetitions of these solutions for $x$) but I'm having a difficult time visualizing any open balls around any points because this is a trigonometric function in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and we want to check if this is open in just $\mathbb{R}$. Since we have $\sin\frac{1}{x}>0$, that would mean everything above the $x$-axis in the graph of $\sin\frac{1}{x}$, so it would include all the points $x$ between $0$ and $\pi$ (not including them), and any $2\pi$ repetitions of those open intervals. So it seems like it would be open, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is an open 'ball' in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JackYoon: $B_r(c) = \{x\in\mathbb R: |x-c| <r\}$. This is, I would say, standard terminology.

Comment: @TonyK
I wasn't actually asking to 'know' what it was. It was more of a hint for the O.P as he seems to be confused about this point.

Comment: This misunderstanding happens often.  Maybe preface a hint with "Hint:" to make sure someone else doesn't jump in.

Comment: @GEdgar Noted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having a difficult time visualizing any open balls

In $\mathbb R$, an open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ is just the open interval $\{y: |y-x|<\epsilon\}=\{y:x-\epsilon<y<x+\epsilon\}=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

---

The mentioned set is an infinite union of open intervals.

$$ A = \left\{x:\sin\frac1x>0\right\} = \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2n\pi},\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi}\right) $$

Thus, by definition of a topology, the set $A$ is also open. (But this does not use metrics I guess it's not the solution your exercise is expecting?)

The set is closed iff $\mathbb R\setminus A=\left\{x:\sin\frac1x\le0\right\}$ is open. But it should be easy to show that the set is not open considering the point $x=\frac1\pi$. Hence $A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of the given set is $$\{x:-1\le \sin^{-1}{1\over x}\le 0\}=\{x: {1\over x}\in \sin^{-1}\big([-1,0]\big) \}$$
this set is closed because sine function is continuous and $[-1,0]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$. So the original set is open.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $\sin\frac1x$ is $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ which is an open set.

The function $\sin\frac1x$ is continuous on its domain, so the inverse image of the open set $(0,\infty)$ is open in its domain. Therefore $\left\{x:\sin\frac1x>0\right\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Lastly, $\mathbb R$ is connected, and $\left\{x:\sin\frac1x>0\right\}$ is a proper open subset, so it is not closed.